# Error linking Matlab with C++

Tags: c++, matlab, g++, matlab-engine

I'm trying to use Matlab library in C++ program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string.h>
#include "engine.h"

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Engine* mweng = engOpen("");
    engEvalString(mweng, "n = func(5)");
    printf ("%d",engGetVariable(mweng, "n"));

    engClose(mweng);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile my project with g++ with included `MATLABROOT\extern\include` directory and have a following error:

```
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/d/Projects/Task1/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `_engOpen'
/cygdrive/d/Projects/Task1/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `_engEvalString'
/cygdrive/d/Projects/Task1/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `_engGetVariable'
/cygdrive/d/Projects/Task1/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `_engClose'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/task1.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

I suppose I have problems with linking some Matlab libs.

UPDATE:
I have same problem with VS2012 and windows compiler. 
Directory `extern\include` included to `Additional include directories`, same as `extern\lib\win64\microsoft` added to linker `Additional library dependencies`. 
According to @jucestain comment, the `libeng.lib` file added to `Additional dependencies` in linker options.

UPDATE 2:
We detected a compatibility problem: 32-bit gcc doesn't work with 64-bit Matlab engine. So, I merged `/extern` folder from 32-bit Matlab with my `/extern` folder, changed included linker library to `/extern/lib/win32/lcc`, and my code has compiled successfully. Thanks to @aircooled!

Comment: What does the documentation tell you? You can start [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1622_files/1622_R13.html)

Comment: Well it's obvious you're missing a link to a library somewhere. This might help you out: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-30UM5H/index.html

Comment: You need to add the path to the lib (.so) file to LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Why not compile with the free Windows SDK?

Comment: @chappjc Building with VC++ compiler gives same error.

Comment: @Everv0id Have you tried the procedure in [Compiling mex files with Visual Studio](http://www.orangeowlsolutions.com/archives/490)?

Comment: @JackOLantern - He's not building a MEX file.

Comment: Looking at the `msvc110engmatopts.bat` file, the only things that stand out as special are an environment variable `MW_TARGET_ARCH=win64`, the 3 MATLAB .libs: `libmx.lib libmat.lib libeng.lib`, the include and lib paths, and putting MATLAB's bin folder on PATH. Maybe try the env variable and restart VS2012.

Comment: @chappjc Where is the file `msvc110engmatopts.bat` located?

Comment: I suspect on 32, 64 bit mix up problem. Check this: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-FWTSV5/?product=ML&solution=1-FWTSV5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the line I use on my cygwin prompt to get main.exe:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -I/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/MATLAB/R2009b/extern/include -L/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/MATLAB/R2009b/extern/lib/win32/microsoft -llibeng
```

Note that order of giving sources and libs for `gcc` is important - first sources, than libs.

Comment: I executed your command:
    `/tmp/ccyvlTD9.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to '_engOpen'
    /tmp/ccyvlTD9.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to '_engClose'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`
I think it's clear that gcc doesn't see microsoft matlab engine libs.

Comment: Do you actually have .lib files in your .../extern/lib/win32/microsoft folder? Is your gcc 32-bit version? Which Matlab version are you running?

Comment: I use 64-bit version of Matlab (R2011b), so I changed your command to the following: `g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -I/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/MATLAB/R2011b/extern/include -L/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/MATLAB/R2011b/extern/lib/win64/microsoft -llibeng`. File `libeng.lib` is located in `/extern/lib/win64/microsoft/`

Comment: What type of binaries your g++ produces, 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: 32-bit gcc. So, do I need to change MATLAB libs to its 32-bit version?

Comment: One note: The libs you link are so called "import" libraries. At run time you need .dll(s) that correspond to those .lib files (libeng.dll in this case).
 
If your .exe is 32-bit it can work only with 32 bit DLLs. You cannot have 32 bit exe load and run 64 bit DLLs (and vice versa).